# I have a task and I am stuck with it [ classes, arrays, cycles ]

Tags: c#

My foreign language is not English, but I'll try to do my best.

*

The transfer between email and servers is happening. Interface speed via internet is known from a file. You need to make a list of servers which haven't got any bite of data in at least one hour period. By having the time when sender sent his email, you can count when the email was fully transferred ( sent ) to the servers. If the transfer ( of the letter ) was fully transferred the next hour, then this hour counts too.   letters.csv ( time the letter was sent, sender, receiver, server's name, letter's size)  servers.csv ( server's name, speed ( bites/second ) ) All the results have to be placed in a .csv file. The results should be written in this order : server's name, letters received, overall size of all letters, how long did it take to transfer all the letters, how long server didn't get any letter. All the letters are sent at the same moment they are received. There should be no server witch was not used at least once.

*

letters.csv example

> 13:15:47;Gustas@inbox.lt;Justas@inbox.lt;Serveris_1;50
>   05:45:11;Tomas@inbox.lt;Simas@inbox.lt;Serveris_3;42
>   12:13:22;Mindaugas@inbox.lt;Justas@inbox.lt;Serveris_3;6
>   07:15:42;Gustas@inbox.lt;Mindaugas@inbox.lt;Serveris_2;19
>   08:18:32;Jonas@inbox.lt;Tomas@inbox.lt;Serveris_1;112

servers.scv example

> Serveris_1;15 
>   Serveris_2;24 
>   Serveris_3;3

**Every example I made myself!**

```
namespace _1
{
    class Letters
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
        private string Sender { get; set; }
        private string Receiver { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public int FileSize { get; set; }

        public Letters() { }
        public Letters(string time, string sender, string receiver, string servername, int filesize)
        {
            Time = time;
            Sender = sender;
            Receiver = receiver;
            ServerName = servername;
            FileSize = filesize;
        }
    }

    class Servers
    {
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public int Speed { get; set; }

        public Servers() { }
        public Servers(string servername, int speed)
        {
            ServerName = servername;
            Speed = speed;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public const int Minute = 60;

        private const int MAX_LETTERS = 50;
        private const int MAX_SERVERS = 5;


        private static int AmmountOfLetters = 0;
        private static int AmmountOfServers = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Letters[] letters = ReadLaiskaiData();
            Servers[] servers = ReadServersData();

            TransferToServers(letters, servers);


        }

        // Reikia sudaryti sąrašą serverių, į kuriuos nebuvo perduota nei vieno baito, kurios nors valandos bėgyje.
        /* PERDAVIMAS Į SERVERIUS   */
        private static void TransferToServers(Letters[] letters, Servers[] servers)
        {
            int speed = 0;
            int f_size = 0;
            int fileSizeLeft = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LETTERS; i++)
            {
                int valanda =  Int32.Parse(letters[i].Time.Substring(0, 2));
                fileSizeLeft = letters[i].FileSize;

                for(int k = valanda; k < (valanda + 24); k++)
                {
                    switch (letters[i].ServerName)
                    {
                        case "Serveris_1":
                        {
                            for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++)
                            {
                                speed = servers[i].Speed;
                                f_size = letters[i].FileSize;
                                fileSizeLeft = letters[i].FileSize - speed;
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", f_size);
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileSizeLeft);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Serveris_2":
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Serveris_3":
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", valanda);
            }
        }

        /* SERVERIŲ SKAITYMAS IŠ FAILO  */
        private static Servers[] ReadServersData()
        {
            Servers[] servers = new Servers[MAX_SERVERS];
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"Serveris.csv"))
            {
                string line = null;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split(';');

                    string servername = values[0];
                    int speed = int.Parse(values[1]);

                    Servers server = new Servers(servername, speed);
                    servers[AmmountOfServers++] = server;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", servername, speed);
                }
            }
            return servers;
        }

        /* LAIŠKŲ SKAITYMAS IŠ FAILO    */
        private static Letters[] ReadLaiskaiData()
        {
            Letters[] letters = new Letters[MAX_LETTERS];
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"laiskai.csv"))
            {   
                string line = null;
                while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split(';');

                    string time = values[0];
                    string sender = values[1];
                    string receiver = values[2];
                    string servername = values[3];
                    int filesize = int.Parse(values[4]);

                    Letters letter = new Letters(time, sender, receiver, servername, filesize);
                    letters[AmmountOfLetters++] = letter;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", time, sender, receiver, servername, filesize);
                }
            }
            return letters; 
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know if I am doing it the right way. I do not have the idea how to do the counting part. I hope I have translated the task understandable. Hopefully any of you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided an answer that matches the length of your examples. It is thorough and feeds you most of this since you provided excellent proof of having tried. I will motivate some of the decisions below the region of source code. Everything should be included.

```
class Letter
{
    public const char FieldSeparator = ';';
    public const char TimeFieldSeparator = ':'; //WARNING: Tweaking this will result in you needing to change .ToString() calls on TimeSpan and DateTime manually

    public DateTime SendDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedReceivedDate => SendDate + (Server != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)Size / Server.TransferRate) : TimeSpan.MaxValue);
    //Traditionally, the server would record this data when it receives it

    public string Sender { get; private set; } //These should be fundamental User / Account classes
    public string Receiver { get; private set; }
    public Server Server { get; private set; }
    public int Size { get; private set; } //We assume this is the size in bytes

    public Letter(DateTime sendDate, string sender, string receiver, Server server, int size)
    {
        SendDate = sendDate;
        Sender = sender;
        Receiver = receiver;
        Server = server;
        Size = size;
    }

    public static Letter Deserialize(string s, IList<Server> servers)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument s: Cannot parse from null or empty string");
        var split = s.Split(FieldSeparator);
        if (split.Length != 5) throw new ArgumentException("Malformed string s! Format: Time " + FieldSeparator + "Sender" + FieldSeparator + "Receiver" + FieldSeparator + "Server" + FieldSeparator + "Size");

        var date = DateTime.Today;
        var timeSplit = split[0].Split(TimeFieldSeparator);
        if (timeSplit.Length != 3) throw new ArgumentException("Malformed time in s! Format: HH" + TimeFieldSeparator + "mm" + TimeFieldSeparator + "ss");
        int hour;
        if (!int.TryParse(timeSplit[0], out hour)) throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse hour from string: " + timeSplit[0]);
        int minute;
        if (!int.TryParse(timeSplit[1], out minute)) throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse minute from string: " + timeSplit[1]);
        int second;
        if (!int.TryParse(timeSplit[2], out second)) throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse second from string: " + timeSplit[2]);
        date = date + new TimeSpan(0, hour, minute, second);

        if (servers == null || servers.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid list of servers passed. No servers mean no message could have been sent.");

        Server server;
        try
        {
            server = servers.First(serv => serv.Name == split[3]);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse server from string: " + split[3] + ". No such server was present in the list passed to the function.");
        }

        int size;
        if (!int.TryParse(split[4], out size)) throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse size from string: " + split[4]);

        var letter = new Letter(date, split[1], split[2], server, size);
        server.Letters.Add(letter);
        return letter;
    }

    public string Serialize(Server s)
    {
        return s.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return SendDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + FieldSeparator + Sender + FieldSeparator + Receiver + FieldSeparator + Server.Name + FieldSeparator + Size;
    }
}

class Server
{
    public const char FieldSeparator = ';';

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int TransferRate { get; set; } //Bytes/Sec
    public IList<Letter> Letters { get; private set; }
    public int BytesReceived => Letters.Sum(l => l.Size);
    public int TotalTransferTime => BytesReceived/TransferRate; 
    //Optionally use public int BytesReceived { get { return Letters.Sum(l => l.Size); } } if C# < 6, this applies to all of these

    public DateTime LastLetterReceiveDate => Letters.Max(letter => letter.EstimatedReceivedDate > DateTime.Now ? DateTime.MinValue : letter.EstimatedReceivedDate);

    public Server(string name, int transferRate, IList<Letter> letters)
    {
        Name = name;
        TransferRate = transferRate;
        Letters = letters;
    }

    public Server(string name, int transferRate, params Letter[] letters)
    {
        Name = name;
        TransferRate = transferRate;
        Letters = new List<Letter>(letters.Length);
        foreach (var letter in letters)
            Letters.Add(letter);
    }

    public static Server Deserialize(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument s: Cannot parse from null or empty string");
        var split = s.Split(FieldSeparator);
        if (split.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException("Malformed string s! Format: Name " + FieldSeparator + "TransferRate");

        int transferRate;
        if (!int.TryParse(split[1], out transferRate)) throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse transfer rate from string: " + split[1]);

        return new Server(split[0], transferRate);
    }

    public string Serialize(Server s)
    {
        return s.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + FieldSeparator + TransferRate;
    }

    public string Summary()
    {
        return Name + FieldSeparator + Letters.Count + FieldSeparator + BytesReceived + FieldSeparator + TotalTransferTime + FieldSeparator + (DateTime.Now - LastLetterReceiveDate).ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static char EntrySeparator = ' ';
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "servers.scv"))) throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find file servers.scv file at path" + Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "servers.scv"));
        var serversscv = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "servers.scv"));

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "letters.csv"))) throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find file servers.scv file at path" + Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "servers.scv"));
        var letterscsv = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "servers.scv"));


        var serversSplit = serversscv.Split(EntrySeparator);
        var lettersSplit = letterscsv.Split(EntrySeparator);

        var servers = new List<Server>(serversSplit.Length);
        var letters = new List<Letter>(lettersSplit.Length);

        servers.AddRange(serversSplit.Select(Server.Deserialize));
        letters.AddRange(lettersSplit.Select(letterString => Letter.Deserialize(letterString, servers)));

        var oldServers = servers.Where(server => (DateTime.Now - server.LastLetterReceiveDate).TotalHours >= 1).Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, oldServer) => current + oldServer);
        var file = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "oldservers.csv"));

        file.WriteLine(oldServers); //Async possible if you're doing a continouous process (ie server does this parsing)
    }
}
```

Now as for the motivation of some of this.

> time the letter was sent, sender, receiver, server's name, letter's size

Makes for a simple class that includes these, that is the result 'Letter'.

> Server's name, speed ( bites/second )

I assumed you meant bytes per second, so I commented that. This info makes the class 'Server'.

> By having the time when sender sent his email, you can count when the email was fully transferred ( sent ) to the servers. If the transfer ( of the letter ) was fully transferred the next hour, then this hour counts too.

I took this and your explanation of how to calculate the received date and made a small property that contains the actual finished transfer date. That resulted in 'EstimatedReceivedDate'.

The serialization is fairly straight forward since you managed that pretty much on your own. I standardized it for you so it's easy to use and extend in the future. What else... let's see. Yeah, the servers have a list of letters because they utilize the letter information quite often. The transfer of information during parsing is done in the Letter's conversion method but there are better approaches to this too. A very portable one would be to add a callback from Letter when it asks for a server and then provide the correct server back to it.

If there's anything unusual you don't understand or want a motivation for other than the above feel free to comment. I feel the rest was fairly obvious and didn't need any extra context.

I will add that, some of the null checks are useless and some of the properties are evaluated more times than they have to so if you need the constraint 'performant' please add that when you write the question. This isn't inefficient but it's not optimized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not even know what to say. That was very helpful and easy understandable. If I have more questions about this task can I contact you via private message? I am going to analyze the code you have written now.

Comment: Sure you're more than welcome to.